# PolylineOptions .color() not working

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, polyline, polylineoptions

I'm trying to set red color on my polylines of my map with this code:

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();
rectOptions.color(R.color.colorPrimary);
String[][] lineInformation = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getLineInformation(line);
for (int i=0; i<lineInformation.length; i++){
    rectOptions.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lineInformation[i][0]),Double.parseDouble(lineInformation[i][1])));
}
```

But it's not working, instead of showing the primaryColour of my app which is red, it's showing a dark color with some alpha.

I followed the official guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is caused by confusion between a *color resource identifier* and a *color value*, both of which are `int`s.

Let's take a look at [the documentation for `PolylineOptions.color()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions.html#color(int)):

> `public PolylineOptions color (int color)`
>
> Sets the color of the polyline as a 32-bit ARGB color. The default color is black (`0xff000000`).

Since the documentation states that the input should be a "32-bit ARGB color", you can't just pass a color resource id; you have to manually resolve that to a color value first.

`R.color.colorPrimary` is an `int` with some auto-generated value, maybe something like `0x7f050042`. Unfortunately, this can be interpreted as an ARGB color, and would be a partially-transparent, extremely dark blue. So the app doesn't crash, you just get an unexpected color on your polyline.

To get the correct color, use `ContextCompat.getColor()` to resolve your color resource id to a color value, and then pass the color value to the `color()` method:

```
Context c = /* some context here */
int colorPrimary = ContextCompat.getColor(c, R.color.colorPrimary);
rectOptions.color(colorPrimary);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the predefined Java "Color" class, to get some standard colors and use it to pass to maps.

For example

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();
<p>rectOptions.color(Color.BLUE);</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Call this method for Draw Polyline and You can add any color for polyline**

```
fun drawPolyline(color: Int, list: ArrayList<LatLng>, googleMap: GoogleMap,width:Float): Polyline {
        val options = PolylineOptions().width(width)
            .color(color)
            .geodesic(true)
        for (z in list.indices) {
            val point = list[z]
            options.add(point)
        }
        return googleMap.addPolyline(options)
    }
```